# Subtracting csr matrices without reducing stored elements

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I'm dealing with subtracting scipy sparse matrices.
Unfortunately if some cell equals 0 after subtracting - it disappears.

What I expect is having it in stored elements, but with value equals zero.

Some oversimplified example:

```
import scipy.sparse as sparse
import numpy as np
row = np.array([0, 1])
col = np.array([0, 1])
data = np.array([1 ,1])
sample_csr=sparse.csr_matrix((data, (row, col)))
display(sample_csr-sample_csr) # what I have
display(sample_csr*0) # what I want
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [844]: row = np.array([0, 1]) 
     ...: col = np.array([0, 1]) 
     ...: data = np.array([1 ,1]) 
     ...: sample_csr=sparse.csr_matrix((data, (row, col)))                                             
In [845]: sample_csr                                                                                   
Out[845]: 
<2x2 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.longlong'>'
    with 2 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [846]: _.A                                                                                          
Out[846]: 
array([[1, 0],
       [0, 1]], dtype=int64)
```

Subtracting 2 matrices returns a new matrix; it does not modify `sample_csr`.

```
In [847]: sample_csr-sample_csr                                                                        
Out[847]: 
<2x2 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.longlong'>'
    with 0 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

You can modify the `data` of matrix, in-place

```
In [848]: sample_csr=sparse.csr_matrix((data, (row, col)))                                             
In [849]: sample_csr.data *= 0                                                                         
In [850]: sample_csr                                                                                   
Out[850]: 
<2x2 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.longlong'>'
    with 2 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

In fact, for efficiency, `sparse.csr` allows a number of changes without figuring out the new sparsity.  You might even get an efficiency warning if you try to do something that requires a change in sparsity (such as adding a nonzero value).

And to clean up the sparsity after a sequence of operations:

```
In [851]: sample_csr.eliminate_zeros()                                                                 
In [852]: sample_csr                                                                                   
Out[852]: 
<2x2 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.longlong'>'
    with 0 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

I don't know of a way of preserving 0s as you want.  Presumably it would require deep changes in how it tracks the sparsity of both operands.

Sparse matrices, especially `csr` format, are optimized for matrix multiplication. Other math like elementwise addition and subtraction is much slower.